# Phaser IO Update dynamically created text on callback

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm currently creating a game using Phaser IO and SignalR (+jQuery), 
I get a list of players from server (for now containing an ID and Name), for each player I create a text field, which I later want to manipulate (with the amount of votes the specific player has), however I have no clue on how to reference the dynamically text object.

I'm open to new ideas as well

```
var game = new Phaser.Game($window.innerWidth, $window.innerHeight, Phaser.Auto, 'gameCanvas');

        var dayState = {
            preload: function () {
                // Preloaded stuff
            },
            create: function () {
                var world = game.world;

                // Players alive in game
                var players = // Call to Server, retrieves list of players

                // Add player 
                for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    var currentPlayer = players[i];

                // Player name
                    game.add.text(world.width - 225, y, currentPlayer.Name);

              // I WANT TO UPDATE THIS UPON CALLBACK
                game.add.text(world.width - 175, y, 0)

                    // Vote button
                        game.add.button(world.width - 50, y + 2, //preloaded texture for button, voteFunction, currentPlayer.Id , 2, 1, 0);                    
                }
            }
        };
        game.state.add('DayState', dayState);
        game.state.start('DayState');

        function voteFunction() {
            // Posts vote to server
        };

function voteReturnedFromServer(amount){
// Server calls this function (SignalR)
// This is where I want to update text element created above with data from SignalR
// Update text with callback data "amount"
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was finding the text after it has been created. I ended up creating an array outside game states and then push the texts into that array. 
Then when I needed to edit the text, I'd search the array using grep (since Im already using jQuery)

```
var game = new Phaser.Game($window.innerWidth, $window.innerHeight, Phaser.Auto, 'gameCanvas');

// This is where I'll push my texts
var voteTexts = [];

        var dayState = {
            preload: function () {
                // Preloaded stuff
            },
            create: function () {
                var world = game.world;

                // Players alive in game
                var players = // Call to Server, retrieves list of players

                // Add player 
                for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    var currentPlayer = players[i];

                // Player name
                    game.add.text(world.width - 225, y, currentPlayer.Name);

              // I WANT TO UPDATE THIS UPON CALLBACK
                var vote = game.add.text(world.width - 175, y, 0)
vote.id = currentPlayer.Id;
voteTexts.push(vote);

                    // Vote button
                        game.add.button(world.width - 50, y + 2, //preloaded texture for button, voteFunction, currentPlayer.Id , 2, 1, 0);                    
                }
            }
        };
        game.state.add('DayState', dayState);
        game.state.start('DayState');

        function voteFunction() {
            // Posts vote to server
        };

function voteReturnedFromServer(amount){
                var textToUpdate = $.grep(voteTexts, function (e) {
                    return e.id === votes.TargetId;
                });
// Since I know there'll be a result and only one, then I use [0]
                textToUpdate[0].text = votes.Count;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go ahead and define a variable at the same level as `game` (for ease), and then set a variable equal to the text you add to the game.

```
var voteText;
// ...


voteText = game.add.text('world.width - 175, y, 0);
```

Then simply update the `text`, if voteText is defined.

```
voteText.text = 'data returned from the server'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in method setText()

```
text.setText(amount);
```

https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Text.html